# WP booking system plugin?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, plugin-events-calendar

I'm a bit overwhelmed with the googling I'm doing and thought I'd turn to the community for recommendations:

I need a booking engine which will :

1. Allow Events to be posted including dates, locations etc
2. Set a max ticket allocation
3. Have Paypal Integration
4. Ability to dump out sales data to a csv would be nice..
5. Perhaps handle returns or refunds

Thanks very much indeed

Comment: are you looking for a free or paid solution? If paid what is your budget?

Comment: either really, nothing that takes a commission on sales though. Free would be preferable

Comment: have a look at this list maybe: http://codecanyon.net/search?term=booking&category=wordpress&ref=woony

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [WP Event Ticketing](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpeventticketing/) plugin which main features include:

- Collect payments via paypal.
- Set total attendance limit.
- Multiple ticket types. For example, ticket type A includes a t-shirt
  while ticket type B does not.
- Custom ticket options. This allows you to decide what information you want ticket purchasers to provide. For example, name, address, shirt size, twitter handle, etc...
- Send email to purchaser upon order completion.
- Reporting page shows total sales and income broken down by package, coupons used and tickets sold.
- Export attendee data to a CSV file.

just watch this video http://vimeo.com/18491170